# Google App Engine - Issue with creating a bulkloading config

Tags: google-app-engine, appcfg

I keep getting the below error while trying to create a bulkloader_config

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
[ERROR   ] Authentication Failed: Incorrect credentials or unsupported authentication type (e.g. OpenId).

Command I am trying to execute

```
appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config --filename=bulkloader.yaml --url=https://<app-id>.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --application=s~<app-id>
```

app.yaml as below

```
application: <app-id>
version: alpha-1-1-2
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

builtins:
- appstats: on
- remote_api: on
```

Help appreciated as to what could be going wrong. The username and password are spot on.